# Open my app for a URI (not URL) in a QR code on Android?

Tags: android, uri, qr-code, intentfilter

I want to encode a URI in a QR code and be able to scan this code using Android's default camera app to open an Activity of my app. Specifically, I want to open a URI that is formatted according to RFC 7565 - but I can't get this to work for any URI that is not an http(s) URL, including "geo:," or any arbitrary URI with a random string for its scheme.

I suspect that it might have to do with Android's URI expecting "//" after the first colon although that is not necessary for a string to be a valid URI - but I am not sure about that.

I declared an intent-filter for one of my app's activities like so:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="acct" />
</intent-filter>
```

Next, I created QR codes for URI strings starting with that scheme, using different online QR code generators as well as the ZXing library from within my app itself. In all cases, scanning the QR code leads to the string being correctly displayed in the camera app with the label "Go to" (suggesting that it is correctly interpreted as some kind of URI), but tapping that button just copies the string to the clipboard instead of opening my app.

I tried adding `android:host="*"` or even other strings to the intent-filter, as well as path strings (that would not be part of the valid acct URI in the first place), but none of that changed anything.

Edit: As was pointed out in the comments, I can try sending the correct URI using `adb shell am start -d "acct:foobar"`, which does in fact open my activity. This means that the intent-filter is set up correctly, but the QR code scanner does not properly interpret the contained string as a URI that could be used in an intent. Is there any way around that?

Comment: If you use `adb shell am start` to start your activity from the command line using your desired `Uri`, does it work? If yes, then the problem lies with the QR code scanner probably. The camera app does not necessarily recognize that your string is a valid `Uri`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Good point, thanks for the idea. `adb shell am start -d "acct:foobar"` does in fact open my activity, so the problem seems to be the scanner.

Comment: "the QR code scanner does not properly interpret the contained string as a URI that could be used in an intent. Is there any way around that?" -- the answer to that would vary by scanner app. Using an `https` URL is the safest route IMHO. The further you go from that pattern, the more likely it is that the scanner will not recognize it as something you can open.

Comment: i am having the same issue any luck solving that other than using https schema

Comment: If the issue is with the scanner app not recognizing a valid Uri, you can set the Uri to https://example.com/app-redirect. Then you can make the server redirect to the app's deep link.

Answer (score 0):

please check with ADB test

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "acct://example.com" com.your.package.name
```

if this will open your application correctly then problem is with your QR code application only.

And 2nd possibility is that other apps (including different versions of your own app) that might have the same intent filter and could be intercepting the intent.